# How to send multiple line text to key/value in MapReduce, not single line

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm studying MapReduce.
I face to some problem.

My data is ...(in example.)

```
<Doc>
<ID> No-001 </ID>
<Value> This is 001 Value. </Value>
</Doc>

<Doc>
<ID> No-002 </ID>
<Value> This is 002 Value. </Value>
</Doc>
...
```

I need to change above text to ...

```
This is 001 Value. No-001
This is 002 Value. No-002
...
```

I want to send multiple line between  and  to value of Mapper in MapReduce. Key is anything. I have searched some example, but I can't this problem.

To solve the problem, I think that I must handle InputFormat.

Please answer the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Mahout XMLinputFormat](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/mahout-0.7-cdh4.1.1/mahout-integration/org/apache/mahout/text/wikipedia/XmlInputFormat.html) class for XML-files' parsing.
It allows you to configure your Driver code like this:

```java
conf.set("xmlinput.start", "<Doc>");
conf.set("xmlinput.end", "</Doc>");
job.setInputFormatClass(XmlInputFormat.class);
```

And then inside your mapper you may process your XML-content with any parser you like.
[There is](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hadoop-practice) a good tutorial for XmlInputFormat class.